# iPad canvas very bad to zero performance

Tags: javascript, performance, ipad, svg, html5-canvas

The javascript library I have created just translates a single picture and zooms it. Touch events and mouse events are used depending on what device.

I ran this javascript code on Firefox (7.0.1), iPhone 3GS (iOS 5.0) and iPhone 4 (iOS 5.0) all with smooth performance, no problem at all.

Then I ran it on iPad 1 (iOS 5.0) with slow performance though zooming and translating the picture works.

Last test was on iPad 2 (iOS 4.3.3) and here I experienced the same slow performance while zooming as iPad 1 but the translating didnt work at all.

I have no clue what this is about, since iPhone is supposed to be alot weaker than an iPad. I would appreciate any help or comments to get me on the right track.

http://pastebin.com/wZ7e77yq

*UPDATE*

I just ran it on an iPad 2 (iOS 5.0) and it works flawlessly. I also tried iPhone 3GS (iOS 4.2.1) and it didnt work, same as iOS 4.3.3. This means that my application needs iOS 5.0 to run... is it really true you couldnt translate objects before iOS 5.0?

*UPDATE2*

I just ran it on three different iPad 1s (iOS 5.0) and it doesnt work very good. What is the big difference in between an iPhone 4 and an iPad 1? Specs are almost identical. Also the translate didnt work because the function event.pageY/X doesnt work prior to iOS 5. This was fixed by using event.touches.pageX/Y instead.

Comment: What version of iOS is each of the devices running? CANVAS is faster in newer versions.

Comment: I updated the versions of the different devices, I hear what you are saying but iPad 1 should perform better than a 3GS.

Comment: iPad 1 will perform worse than 3GS for the same reason that iPhone 4 should perform worse than 3GS: it has higher screen resolution (2x or greater). Canvas is very render-intense and takes more memory on iPad than on 3GS. In that case it should be very dramatic. iPad vs iPhone 4 is odd - there is only minimal resolution difference (1024x768 vs 960x640). It could be that Safari UI on iPad is more memory intense than iPhone?

Comment: What do you mean by Canvas != SVG? I am using both the canvas and a SVG matrix for calculations which means they both could be involved.

Comment: I have a hard believing that iPad wouldnt be able to handle a couple of matrix calculations after seeing some of the games. I have one more test to run, tomorrow I am gonna try a different iPad 1 (iOS 5.0) to see if the one I got is broken.

Comment: By CANVAS != SVG, in web browsers two are completely different methods for rendering scalable graphics. SVG is supported by all browsers going back even to IE6, whereas CANVAS is an HTML5 feature only.

Comment: Ok I see, I use canvas for rendering. Do you think the SVG matrix has something to do with the slow performance?

Comment: illion, see the answer I added below. Could you run that test?

Comment: Yes I am on it, in meetings all day but Ill try to run it during lunch.

Comment: Ok I have tried three different iPad 1 (iOS5.0) and none of them runs the application smoothly. This is very weird since the difference between iPhone 4 and iPad is not very big at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like perhaps iOS CANVAS support was the issue. iOS5 has full GPU hardware-accelerated CANVAS support, while previous versions supported CANVAS albeit very poorly.

Surprised that it does not work well on iPad 1 even with iOS 5, though. Can you try closing all currently-running apps, close all other browser tabs, and run the test again?

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work, I even reinstalled one of the iPads but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was developing a small game for testing canvas performance without any special game framework so I kept it simple because I was writing it by myself. The program did nothing special, just moving a sprite around the screen with different joystick types, such as keyboard and mouse for desktop click, and touch events for iOS. I discovered the following:

- Using taps direct on the canvas results in poor performance compared to touch events.
- Touch events worked well with different canvas sizes up to 1024x768.
- I didn't try picture zooming, but that should have be fine as well.
- event.pageX, event.pageY worked without problems on iPad (iOS5).

I hope that helps.